# Can every prime be written as $\large \frac{p+q}{2} \pm 1$ for $p,q$ primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

While writing code to play with primes, I noticed all even numbers satisfy

$\large 2n = \frac{p+q}{6}$

so any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as

$\large n = \frac{p+q}{12}$

However, prime numbers have this form

$\large 6n\pm 1$

Substituting $n$

$\large 6(\frac{p+q}{12}) \pm 1$

gives

$\large \frac{p+q}{2} \pm 1$

Next, ran the program to confirm some primes

$\large 5 = \frac{5+7}{2} - 1$

...

$\large 101 = \frac{5+199}{2} - 1$

...

$\large 5003 = \frac{31+9973}{2} + 1$

...

and seems to hold this pattern indefinitely.

**Question**

Is this pattern a conjecture or can it be proven?

Comment: This would be true assuming the Goldbach conjecture. I wouldn't be surprised if it's unsolved otherwise.

Comment: This **is** the Goldbach conjecture, rearranged. If prime $r=\frac{p+q}{2}\pm 1$, then $p+q=2(r\pm 1)$. But numbers $2(r\pm 1)$ are just a subset of the even numbers, every one of which ($\ge 4$) Goldbach conjectures to be representable by some $p+q$.

Comment: It is slightly weaker than Goldbach since for every given prime $s$ , only one of $2(s-1)$ and $2(s+1)$ must be the sum of two primes , but I do not think that this makes the conjecture that every prime has such a representation significantly easier to prove.

Comment: But since Golbach's conjecture almost surely is true , we need not worry about the existence of a prime having no such representation , even more we can safely assume that every positive integer can be written as desired.